# Composite Pattern: Is the root a simple Composite?

Tags: java, design-patterns, composite

To implement the Composite pattern in Java I have an abstract class Component with the functions `getChild(int i)`, `add(Component c)`, `remove(Component c)`, `forAllDo()` and `getChildren()`.

It is implemented by the two classes Leaf and Composite.

Leaf throws for nearly every function an exception - only for `forAllDo()`, something is done with it.
How would you implement the Root?
I would understand it as a normal Composite class - all the functions make the same sense. Have you any arguments that that is not the case?

Comment: In short: `Component` should be an interface, not an abstract class. `Leaf` and `Composite` both implements the `Component` interface. So for the client it's irrelevant if root is a leaf or not, since it implements `Component` interface. If you have only one element in the tree, the root is a leaf, because there's no point in having a composite object. In other cases it becomes a composite.

Comment: Root has to be a `Composite` in order to build a **hierarchy**. A **Client** operating on a **composition** doesn't need to be aware of **hierarchy**, until the client is operating on `abstract` methods in your `Composite` class, using abstract class should be fine